# What's the difference between "you answer" and "you'll be answering"

Tags: grammar

I heard this sentence that a native guy said :

> Soon, you all will be answering to him.

and my question is that why the speaker didn't say :

> Soon, you all should answer to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is *not* in the passive voice, it is the continuous tense. You don't give us the context, but it looks like a prediction - that before long 'he' will be in a position of authority, the person that people have to [answer to](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/answer-to).

Your second version is a recommendation; it doesn't have the same meaning (and doesn't make much sense).

Comment: Thanks, according to what you said if I make such a sentence would it be true to say : [for example the president is sick] **If the president dies, people will be voting for a new one, two months later**

Comment: The first sentence could possibly be used in that situation.